# Find text after specified element until next specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, tei

I ran into this problem: Im using TEI anchor elements to describe text lines. To describe these lines I am using an **anchor** element (which is an *empty element*) at the beginning and **anchor** element (which is also an *empty element*) at the end of each line.

I hope the following example helps to describe the situation.

```
<p>
   <anchor type="start" n="line1" rend="x1,y1,r1"/> This <b>is</b> text <anchor type="end" n="line1"/>
   <anchor type="start" n="line2" rend="x2,y2,r2"/> This is text <anchor type="end" n="line2"/>
   <anchor type="start" n="line3" rend="x3,y3,r3"/> This is text <anchor type="end" n="line3"/>
</p>
```

Now I want to take each text fragment (which is situated between two anchor elements of the same **n**-attirube), and wrap it in a own DIV.

For this approch I tried to use this code (this is **example** code, so please don't nail me on syntax):

```
$( "anchor[type='start']" ).each(function()
    {
        $(this).nextUntil( "anchor[type='end']").each(function()
            {
                $(this).wrap( "<div  n='#' style='doSomething'/>" );
            });
        }
    );
```

Now, I know the jquery **nextUntil()** function is not working on text nodes. **That is why I am asking**. Do you guys know some walk arround here?